# How to store and use the value of a batch file for loop variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a Windows batch file where I'm trying to perform some operation on every file with a given name within a directory tree.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s %1 ^| findstr /c:"Directory of"') do (
    set dir=%%i
    echo i = %%i
    echo dir = %dir:~14%
)
```

My problem is that *dir* is always equal to the last element found in the for loop. So I may get output like this. (alignment added for clarity)

```
i = Directory of c:\alpha\myfile.txt
dir =            c:\charlie\myfile.txt
i = Directory of c:\bravo\myfile.txt
dir =            c:\charlie\myfile.txt
i = Directory of c:\charlie\myfile.txt
dir =            c:\charlie\myfile.txt
```

So *dir* is never equal to "alpha" or "charlie".

What do I need to do to get the functionality I'm looking for?

Comment: why don't you put your functionality within the loop?check also if you need delayedExpansion ->http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s %1 ^| findstr /c:"Directory of"') do (
 set dir=%%i
 echo i = %%i
 call :process
)

goto :eof

:process
echo dir = %dir:~14%
goto :eof
```

Note that within the internal subroutine `:process`, `%%i` is not available. The `call :process` requires the colon and `goto :eof` means go to physical end-of-file (which terminates the subroutine) where the colon is required but `:EOF` is understood and shouldn't be assigned as a label.

Possibly better would be

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b %1') do (
 set dir=%%i
 echo i = %%i
 call :process
)

goto :eof

:process
echo dir = %dir%
goto :eof
```

YMMV

Answer (score 0):

two examples:

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('dir /s ^|findstr /bc:" Directory of"') do echo %%~b
```

---

```
for /r %%a in (.) do echo %%~fa
```

Comment: That's a handy way of getting rid of my %dir:~14%, but once I try to do anything more substantial than "do echo %%~b" I have the same problem as before.

Answer (score 0):

This reports the path and also the full filespec.

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (myfile.txt) do echo "%%~dpa" and full path is "%%a" & pause
```

Comment: This seems to show 'myfile.txt' is in every directory, not just the ones it actually exists in.